# modify a digit of string in a file line by arithmetic

Tags: bash

On a clearly specific line of my file, for example let's say Line 93, I have a coordinate of 3 components in the range [0.0, 1.0). I want to add the first and the second number by 0.5 or -0.5, making it still in the range [0.0, 1.0), while leaving the third number unchanged. How can I write a script to do this through `sed` or `awk` or anything else? There's a batch of files to be processed, thanks a lot for help.

Input:

```
...
  0.6004778515530910  0.3354932652277851  0.0828914297825582
...
```

Output:

```
...
  0.1004778515530910  0.8354932652277851  0.0828914297825582
...
```

ps: Another feature is that the tenths digit of the first number is always the 5th of the string (there are two spaces at the front), and the second is always the 25th. I'm not sure whether this will make the task easier.

Comment: Please show what you did and explain why it does not work as you expected.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I've no idea doing this right now. If I do ```sed 'y/0123456789/5678901234/g'```, each digit will be modified, while doing ```sed 's/ 0.0/ 0.5'/g``` and its counterparts ten times will not work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

```bash
$ awk -v CONVFMT='%.16f' '{$1+=($1<0.5)?0.5:-0.5; $2+=($2<0.5)?0.5:-0.5; print}' file
0.1004778515530910 0.8354932652277851 0.0828914297825582
```

Explanation: The `CONVFMT` GNU `awk` variable specifies the conversion format for numbers; `%.16f` means 16 digits after the radix character.

`$1+=($1<0.5)?0.5:-0.5` adds `0.5` to the first field if it is less than `0.5`, else it subtracts `0.5`. `$2+=($2<0.5)?0.5:-0.5` does the same for the second field. And `print` prints the modified record.

If you want to keep the 2 leading spaces use `print "  " $0` instead of just `print`:

```bash
$ awk -v CONVFMT='%.16f' '{$1+=($1<0.5)?0.5:-0.5; $2+=($2<0.5)?0.5:-0.5; print "  " $0}' foo.txt 
  0.1004778515530910 0.8354932652277851 0.0828914297825582
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo '  0.6004778515530910  0.3354932652277851  0.0828914297825582' |
```

> ```
> mawk '$!NF=sprintf("\n\t%s\n\t%.*s%.f%.*s%d%s", $(_<_),
>       _+=_+=_^=_<_,$!_,(++_+substr($!_,_,!!_)) %(_+_),_*_-++_,
>       substr($!_,_),(substr($!_,--_*_,!!_)+_) %(_+_),
>                      substr($!_,_*_+(_^=!_)))'
> ```

```
      0.6004778515530910  0.3354932652277851  0.0828914297825582
      0.1004778515530910  0.8354932652277851  0.0828914297825582
```

Comment: This works, but could you please make an illustration, thank you!

Comment: @Rabbiiiiit : the illustration i made was already exactly the test case you provided - just take both those digits, add `+5` to it, `modulo-% 10`, and do substrings for the rest of stuff before and after it - this way i don't need to check whether it's above or below `0.5`, since the wrap-around nature of modulo ensures that will happen

Comment: and by doing it entirely in string ops, i avoid having to worry corrupting the right most digits due to lack of precision, or rounding peculiarities